# simulating two arducopter in with single mavproxy

Tags: python, dronekit-python, mavlink

I have tried to create multiple instance of mav proxy but i have no idea about this.
   My question is about how to load two arducopter in single map in sitl. I am learning sitl setup and i want to know is it possible to load two arducopter in one map?

Answer (score 1):

I've successfully managed to do a swarming/flocking simulation using `Dronkit-SITL` and `QGroundControl`. The thing is that the SITL TCP ports are hard-coded in the `ArduPilot` firmware. If you wanna simulate with multiple vehicles, you are gonna have to modify the SOURCE CODE of `ArduPilot` and compile from source for each vehicle separately.

For instance, a swarming simulation of 5 vehicles requires 5 different vehicle firmware coded with different TCP ports. Also, the simulated `eeprom.bin` should  be slightly adjusted to work properly (or even fit real vehicles).

Basically, monitoring the TCP ports should work fine with both `Dronekit-SITL` and `Mavproxy` so it should be no problem to do multi-vehicle simulation in `Mavproxy`.

Some more details can be found on my Github repo (although the Readme is quite long). Hope it helps!

https://github.com/weskeryuan/flydan

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to do something related to swarms? 
In ardupilot website they mentioned the following:

> Using SITL is just like using **a** real vehicle.

I do not think it is possible but it is better to post your question in [Ardupilot forum community](https://discuss.ardupilot.org/).

I like the idea and it will be extremely useful.

Answer (score 0):

From the [MAVProxy docs](https://ardupilot.github.io/MAVProxy/html/getting_started/multi.html):

> MAVProxy is designed to control 1 vehicle per instance. Controlling multiple vehicles would require a substantial re-design of MAVProxy and is not currently on the "to-do" list.
>
> However, there is very limited support for displaying (not controlling) multiple vehicles on the map. This should be considered an experimental feature only, as it was developed for a specific application (2016 UAV Challenge) where two UAV's were required to be displayed on a single map.

If all you need is to view them both in one map, then the instructions there should work for you.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot run two vehicles in one MAP on Mavproxy.
What you can do is run two simulators and track them on Mission Planner or QGC.

To run two unstance you need to specify different instance numbers.

```
python3 ardupilot/Tools/autotest/sim_vehicle.py -j4 -v ArduCopter    -M --map --console --instance 40   --out=udpout:127.0.0.1:14550

python3 ardupilot/Tools/autotest/sim_vehicle.py -j4 -v ArduCopter    -M --map --console --instance 50   --out=udpout:127.0.0.1:14551
```

Note **instance 40 & 50**... also note the **out=udpout** ports **14551** & **14550**